# How does buffering objects in a raster data set differ from buffering in a vector data set?

Tags: raster, buffer

How does buffering objects in a raster data set differ from buffering in a vector data set?
What are the steps on making a raster buffer?

Comment: Using what GIS software? What have you tried?